# How to show table to avoid table cutting off from page?

Tags: tables, scalebox

I have this table, but I can not show all the table in the page, How can I scale the table to be shown within the page?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cccc|cccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Dataset}} & \textbf{Data type} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Some technique for multi dimensional (method one + method two)}}                        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{time(µ s)}}                                                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{n}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{v}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ww}} & \textbf{K\_} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{S}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{M}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{WQ}} & \textbf{QR} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A1}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{96}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.3}         & 1.64         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{67}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{117}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5623}        & 34          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A2}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{81}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.57}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.77}        & 3.34         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{78}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{875}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{734}         & 2923        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A3}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{734}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4.59}        & 6.68         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{34}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{653}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8453}        & 286         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B1}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{87}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.44}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.75}        & 2.53         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{54}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{743}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8954}        & 763         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B2}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{678}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.51}        & 5.07         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{66}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{789}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7635}        & 834         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B3}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{87}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9.61}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.03}        & 10.14        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{379}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{765}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8734}        & 562         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C1}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19.89}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.59}        & 8.01         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{843}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9268}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9834}        & 982         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C2}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{44.2}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26.52}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{15.18}       & 7            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{652}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9745}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8734}        & 457         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C4}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{27.31}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18.61}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6}           & 16.48        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{87}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4319}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11345}       & 693         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C4}               & int                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47.1}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{75}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9}           & 21.98        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7642}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8723}        & 1137        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output for @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer

[image]

**log file:**

[image]

Comment: Stay away from these awful online table generators. With all the interfering `\multicolumn`, properly formatting your table is much harder than it should be.

Comment: So how can I generate a table in easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from these awful online table generators. With all the interfering `\multicolumn`, properly formatting your table is much harder than it should be.

Instead I suggest to

- use the `tabularray` package which makes it easy to merge cells for your headline
- use the `siunitx` package to properly align the numbers in your table
- have a look at the documentation of the `booktabs` package for some inspiration how to format a professional looking table. Hint: vertical lines are not part of such a layout

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={
    @{}
    X[halign=c]
    X[halign=c]
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=3.2]
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=3.0]
    S[table-format=4.0]
    S[table-format=5.0]
    S[table-format=4.0]
    @{}
  },
  cells={valign=m},
  row{1-2}={guard},
  hspan=minimal
}
\toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{} Data Set &  \SetCell[r=2]{} Data type & \SetCell[c=4]{} Some technique for multi dimensional (method one + method two) &&&& \SetCell[c=4]{} time(µs)                                 &&&                                           \\ 
\cmidrule[r]{3-6}\cmidrule[l]{7-11}
& & n & v & ww & K\_ & S & M & WQ & QR \\ 
\midrule
A1               & int                & 4          & 96         & 1.3         & 1.64         & 67         & 117        & 5623        & 34          \\ 
A2               & int                & 81         & 1.57       & 2.77        & 3.34         & 78         & 875        & 734         & 2923        \\ 
A3               & int                & 33         & 734        & 4.59        & 6.68         & 34         & 653        & 8453        & 286         \\ 
B1               & int                & 87         & 7.44       & 1.75        & 2.53         & 54         & 743        & 8954        & 763         \\ 
B2               & int                & 9          & 678        & 3.51        & 5.07         & 66         & 789        & 7635        & 834         \\ 
B3               & int                & 87         & 9.61       & 7.03        & 10.14        & 379        & 765        & 8734        & 562         \\ 
C1               & int                & 7          & 19.89      & 7.59        & 8.01         & 843        & 9268       & 9834        & 982         \\ 
C2               & int                & 44.2       & 26.52      & 15.18       & 7            & 652        & 9745       & 8734        & 457         \\ 
C4               & int                & 27.31      & 18.61      & 6           & 16.48        & 87         & 4319       & 11345       & 693         \\ 
C4               & int                & 47.1       & 75         & 9           & 21.98        & 5          & 7642       & 8723        & 1137        \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the first sentence in answer :-). For first two rows you can (should) use `row{1-2} = {guard}` and than omit all curly braces in those rows needed for proper work of the `S` columns.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot for the `guard` trick!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , please could you see the update question? and I have red line under \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

Comment: @ayla Is your `tabularray` package up-to-date? Can you add your .log file to your question?

Comment: @ayla You seem to be using overleaf. I just tested the example from my answers and it seems to work without error https://www.overleaf.com/read/crmqtqnvyvdk Did you try the exact same code as in my answer or do you get the error for your real document? Also check in the left hand sidebar which version of texlive your are using.

Comment: Yes, I am using overleaf and the lextlive is 2021.

Comment: @ayla Try with 2022

Comment: I can not compile the  document with lextlive 2022 :(

Comment: I change the compiler to Fast [draft] and not it work !

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, if I insert another two column I faced the same problem I can not show all the table ,how can scale the table please?

Comment: @ayla Scaling tables is a bad idea. Better change the layout to something that will fit.

Answer (score 0):

If You have a larger line width the first 2 columns are too large. So I have modified just a little bit the
samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
excellent answer to center the table and to have fixed width for the first two columns:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={
                    @{}
                    X[halign=c,.5in]
                    X[halign=c,.5in]
    ...
```

In the preamble I fixed a different (larger) geometry of the page.
The output is something like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you! how to format one row of table as bold?